# Printing the value of a variable

Tags: java

Help ppl!
I am debating about courses about my university degree, and I have doing some research about my choices. I am definitely going to study something to do with computing, so I have started practicing some software development in both Java and C++,. but my first Java one that I have developed does run but doesn't gave me the correct answer so I was wondering if someone would kindly help me by looking at it. Here's it and when it executed, only RESULT appears don't know why.
Please take a look and help:

```
public class Math1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num1, num2, result;
        num1 = 90;
        num2 = 40;
        result = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("result");
    }
}
```

When terminated, only RESULT I can see. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us details about your error! What do you expect to see?

Comment: That is because you are passing it the string result, not the variable result.

Comment: This is a very basic error - I think you will benefit most if you investigate / study the language and solve this yourself.

Comment: Does my answer below resolve your issues?

Answer (score 2):

I'm wildly guessing what you're asking here, if you intend to see `50`, you need to change

```
System.out.println("result"); //This will print: result
```

to

```
System.out.println(result); //This will print: 50
```

Reason: `"result"` is the String literal `"result"`, if you want to refer to the variable `result`, you need to remove the quotes.

Besides that, your code seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting the string 'result' instead of the result variable. Use this: System.out.println(result);

Answer (score 0):

Change `System.out.println("result");` with this `System.out.println(result);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using " " around your string. This, like said, it printing the string "result". Remove the quotes to reference the variable.

```
System.out.println(result);
```